# How do I get my website to display Welcome to Rails instead of Index of / in Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-5.2

duelingpetWS2 droplet
address: http://68.183.163.139/

Currently installed:

```
NodeJS
NPM
Rbenv
ruby 2.5.1p57
Rails 5.2.2
MySQL
Ubuntu 18.04
nginx
```

/var/www/duelingpets.net/html/index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Duelingpets.net!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Success!  The duelingpets.net server block is working!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

New Version
/etc/nginx/sites-available/duelingpets.net

```
upstream duelingpets {
  server unix:///path/to/web/tmp/puma.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/duelingpets.net/html;
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name duelingpets.net www.duelingpets.net;
        try_files $uri @app;

        location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://duelingpets;
        }
}
```

Old version
/etc/nginx/sites-available/duelingpets.net

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/duelingpets.net/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name duelingpets.net www.duelingpets.net;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/duelingpets.net /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
```

Current Behavior of the site.

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

Comment: Show your apache config for the rails app, it's pointing to the /public directory and not forwarding the requests to the rails appserver process

Comment: Okay I just edited my original post and added the apache2 sites-available conf file. Okay which part should it point to? Rails 3.2 you originally had to point it to the /public directory to make it work. Where does it need to point to for Rails 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Puma as rails' app server, check this ticket: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/125

It sets this config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    NameVirtualHost 99.99.99.99
    ServerName yourapp.com
    ServerSignature Off
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyVia On
</VirtualHost>
```

Note the proxypass to localhost:3000, this is the important part (you don't need document root).

And make sure you start puma with `puma -b tcp://127.0.0.1:3000` so it works via tcp instead of sockets.

Anyway, I prefer using nginx instead of apache, you can set nginx to use sockets which is how puma starts by default and there are more tutorials for nginx+puma (there's the config for nginx on that link too).

Comment: I just tested this and was not able to get it working with the code you provided. Is it possible to do it the other way with the document root? I am using puma rails since it is the default. I have used both apache and nginx in the past but I only have a single core. I prefer it if I don't have to start the puma service and have it run automatically, since this is going to be a remote server. I also like to eventually put it into production mode if possible. In the past I used the document root make things work. I attached the old apache2 version that works on my live site.

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do that, it's either tcp with the proxypass to localhost or using the socket. If you want the puma process to run automatically check systemd or place a script on /etc/init.d to start the server automatically.

Comment: Okay. So how do I get it to run via the socket version? I am curious if I am missing something as that one is a bit closer to complete. I think right now by default I think puma is running when applied to digital ocean servers. I am guessing that as I have rails already running automatically.

Comment: I guess rails won't run automatically without you configuring it, you can check it starting the vps and running `ps ax | grep 'puma'` and check if there's a puma process running. The link on my answer shows the config to use sockets with nginx (not sure if apache supports sockets).

Comment: Seeing as apache is being a bit of a pain I am going with nginx now. So what do I do to get started?

Comment: I got nginx working but now it is displaying only the nginx code  and not the welcome to ruby on rails code. I need some help to figure this out. How do I fix it? I followed the digital ocean nginx tutorial exactly for ubuntu 18.04 so why won't it display?

Comment: I think you're making it more difficult for your self by running multiple web servers. Effectively one webserver has to serve another which serving another etc. That leads to a very complicated setup. Consider running a single one: Either Apache, nginx, or puma, but not multiple.

Comment: @EmilKampp, the way rails works you need a webserver (nginx or apache) AND an app server (puma, passenger, unicorn) running at the same time.

Comment: @Eric show your current configuration, it's hard to tell what may be wrong if you don't show what you have done.

Comment: If you insist on such a convoluted setup, I will leave you to it. Good luck.

Comment: @EmilKamp: Your right I am making this way too complicated. I am removing all the servers and will only focus on one server which is duelingpetsWS2 configuration. Arieljuod: I am working on building this new server with one set of configuration and will revamp my original post.

Comment: I just fixed it up so now it is using the nginx engine only but still it is displaying just the nginx welcome message and nothing else. Any advice?

Comment: @Eric I have already posted the config for nginx+puma (it's on the link on my answer), I don't know what else to tell you. You postead your current config and you not using sockets nor tcp proxy (both options on that link), you are not doing anything to pass the request from nginx to the rails process.

Comment: @arieljuod: I just changed it now to the information provided in the link answer and it still is showing the nginx welcome page. I also don't know what to set the upstream puma syntax to

Comment: I saw this config information but its for an older version. I don't really understand how to setup puma. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04. Puma is running on Rails 5.2 by default but I just don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: That link you just posted has a complete guide, it has the config files, the commands to copy and move the configurations, how to star/stop/restart puma, how to set that to start automatically on boot, how to configure nginx to use the unix socket with puma, everything is there, what exactly you don't understand?. Follow the tutorial step by step and then you'll find concrete questions to ask, it's all there on the link.

Comment: I ran this statement: RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create and got this as a result: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Couldn't create 'duelingpets' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Okay I am now using my normal user for my website and not the root. So now I am getting this error message: production rake db:create
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/duelingpets.net/html/Duelingpets/tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache.15723.48962.tmp

Comment: You need to set the right permisions on the database for your user, you can set the rails app inside your user's home folder so you don't have to deal with permission writing files. I'd suggest to search stackoverflow with those errors since there are A LOT of queston about them. Then, if you can't find an answer, create a new question with that problem, it doesn't make sense to follow this here on the comments. Deploy your web to something like `/home/youruser/duelingpets` and you'll be able write to run the task (if you gave permissions and configured the database.yml too).

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the directory to my other user. I think this area right here might be the cause of it. For some reason it keeps calling default even though I setup a username and password in the production section. Should I delete default? default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: If this doesn't work I might wind up switching to the place that you mentioned. I don't want to do that if I can avoid it. So here is what the production environment looks like: production:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: Duelingpets
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DUELINGPETS_DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DUELINGPETS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

Comment: I decided to try my home directory but I got this error instead. Access denied for user 'duelingpets'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Couldn't create 'Duelingpets' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'duelingpets'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Did you set those environment variables on your server (DUELINGPETS_DATABASE_USER/PASSWORD)? Really, you must search stackoverflow first (this is something that sure has been asked a lot of times) and, if you still have problems, `create a new question`, there's no sense on keep this going on on the comments. Read stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: Yes I do have a user and password set up in the .rbenv-vars file. I think I will open up a new question.